# How can i call the parent-window jquery function with variable from popup window javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I call the parent-window jquery function with variable from popup window javascript? Any simple examples that I can look at?

Comment: What kind of variable are you passing? selector? html string? function? DOM element (ouch)?

Comment: Does parent.$(something) work?  Seems like it should.

Comment: just a string to a parent window function from popupwindow.

Comment: What kind of string? A selector string? An html snippet?

Comment: a string sent from parent_window to popup window through GET(indicating the state of parent_window). while closing the popup i want to pass the string(some thing like '1' or '2') back to the parent_window function after parent window reloads, so that it can get the old state.

Comment: Err, what does this have to do with jQuery then?

Comment: This is just a rephrasing of your other question.  You already have the correct syntax in the other thread you made.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1878398/jquery-help

Comment: The correct syntax is not working, thats why i need the general approach to solve that problem. i just want to know how to handle jquery in this situation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[opener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.opener) is a reference to the `window` object of the opening document. I.e. you have access to the global javascript namespace of the opening window.

e.g.

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.pack.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      function foo(url) {
        // if there is a reference to the opening window
        if (null!=opener) {
          // we call the function in the context of the opening window
          opener.foo(url);
        }
        else {
          // otherwise show the data
          $('#d1').html(new Date() + " : " + url);
        }
      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="d1">...</div>
    <button onclick="window.open('?');">new window</button>
    <button onclick="foo(document.URL);">propagte url</button>
  </body>
</html>
```

if you press "propagate url" in a (in any) popup window the function call will bubble up to the first non-popup window (having opener=null).

edit: keep in mind that security restrictions (like cross domain checks) implemented in the browser apply.

edit2: example with history.go(0)

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.pack.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      function foo() {
        var context = (null!=opener) ? opener : window;
        context.history.go(0);
      }

      $(document).ready( function() {
        $('#d1').html("document ready at "+ new Date());
      });
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="d1">...</div>
    <button onclick="window.open('?');">new window</button>
    <button onclick="foo(document.URL);">...and action</button>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you. 
just add "opener.history.go(0);" before "opener.foo(url);" , now it is not working ( for me), any suggestions.

Comment: yes, i am changing some of the main-window content in the popup, so i want it to reload with edited contents, and used history.go(0) for restoring the same page view as before.

Comment: I think i may need when the main window reloading completes,so that i can call the jquery in it(main window). i tried with window.parent.onload=function_name; but it did't worked. any other way?

Comment: Fine, after "context.history.go(0)" i want to execute some function. like "opener.foo(url);" . that fn. not working.after reloads. any ideas to check the completion of parent window reloading.

Comment: Now that's an interesting question. I somehow doubt you can use $(opener.document).ready() for that, though I haven't tested it. If it doesn't work you should open another question on _that_ specific matter.

Answer (score 2):

Normally you define a plugin function like this:

```
(function($) {  // jquery no conflict

$.fn.myPlugin = function(myvar){
    // do something
}

})(jQuery);
```

Then use this:

```
window.opener.$.fn.myPlugin(myvar);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
window.opener.jQuery(myVariable);
```

Comment: thanks for ur reply. i think "myVariable" is function name, if i correct, how to pass variable to it.If it is variable how to call my function?

Comment: maybe you need window.opener.myFunction(someVariable)

Comment: exactly, but how to define "myFunction(somevariable)" in parent window jquery.

Comment: function myFunction(somevariable) { /* like this? */ }

Comment: Fine, i tried, but in the function i wrote some jquery line. that is not working, so i want to know when parent window onload completes, how to find that is the question now?